# I can not see the table dba_object

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am trying to perform this query and did not return anything, tells me that the table does not exist

```
SELECT * FROM dba_object WHERE object_name LIKE 'v$*'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both answers above are correct, however there is also a possibility that this could be a permissions issue.  If you are logged in as a user who doesn't have permission to this table it will give a table does not exist error.

you can check if your current user has access with the below (replacing username with the appropriate logged in user)...

```
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS where table_name = 'DBA_OBJECTS' and GRANTEE = 'username';
```

If you do not have permissions you will need to log in as SYS and grant permissions to this table or talk to your DBA to get this done.

Answer (score 5):

The table is named `DBA_OBJECTS`, in plural:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_2243.htm

And the `*` sign should be replaced by `%`:

```
SELECT * FROM dba_objects WHERE object_name LIKE 'V$%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle is case sensitive. You should probably use an uppercase `V` in your `LIKE` clause and change `*` to `%`:

```
SELECT * FROM dba_objects WHERE object_name LIKE 'V$%'
```

Also the correct catalog view name is `dba_objects`.